# Question on "hard time"

Tags: word-usage

Are there any other words or expressions to mean "hard time"?

For example, I'd like to say,
I had a hard time waking up this morning.

Is there any word to mean difficult other than hard time? one word is preferred. It must have been so much better if "hardly" meant the same as "hard time", but it doesn't.

Comment: I'm having difficulty works.

Comment: Is there no -ly version adverb?

Comment: You could use: I had a difficult time... I had issues..I had trouble... I had problems...Do any of those work for you?

Comment: Challenge and struggle are both nouns that can replace "hard time"

Comment: If you're looking for an adverb in particular, then you could use **reluctantly**, although that really means that you *didn't want*  to wake up, not necessarily that it was difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have an adverb to replace "have a hard time".

"Barely" is close, but there's a distinction--"had a hard time" means you encountered difficulties, "barely" means it almost didn't happen. "Had a hard time" looks at the process, "barely" looks at the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some adverbs that come to mind:

> I woke up [...] this morning.

- Tiredly
- Exhaustingly
- Arduously
- Roughly

Though I would say that none sound quite as natural as "I had a **hard time** waking up" or "I had a **rough time** waking up".

Comment: These only work with the O.P.'s example sentence. I think the OP is looking for a more **general** term that would also work with, say: _I had a hard time starting my car_, or: _We had a hard time writing that program_.